# Spring security internazionalization messages are not overriding

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hi im trying to override the english default messages for spring security but i have some specific messages that aren't getting the overrode message those are my codes.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages/messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="es_MX"/>
    <property name="cookieName" value="gb"/>
    <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="4800"/>
</bean>

<bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

For this one the message is correct:

```
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials=La clave de usuario y/o contraseña son incorrectas
```

the message showed in jsp is:

> La clave de usuario y/o contraseña son incorrectas

but for this one:

```
ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy.exceededAllowed=Esta cuenta ya esta siendo utilizada
```

i am getting this message:

> Maximum sessions of 1 for this principal exceeded

The message is printed in the jsp like this:

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.login_error}">
  <p class="text-danger text-center"><strong>${sessionScope.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.localizedMessage}</strong></p>
</c:if>
```

As you can see the message is correctly translated im my custom messages, but is not correct in the application, somebody can help me.

i am using the next libraries

- Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE
- Spring security 3.2.7.RELEASE
- Apache tiles 3.0.5

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that message key has been changed in Spring's [Java code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/session/ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.java#L138), but not in [messages bundle](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/security/messages.properties). The reason that you get English message is because there is default message provided in Java code I linked to.

Try:

```
ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.exceededAllowed=Esta cuenta ya esta siendo utilizada
```

and it should work.

Edit:
There is even an issue created on [Spring's JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2746) for this.